# Assign a value to a component variable inside RxJS's subscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to subscribe to an observable source in order to bind the source's value to a component variable (`event: Event`).

In spite of the fact that the observer function passed to the `subscribe()` function executes correctly, and the observable arrives at expected, the component variable `event: Event` is always undefined.

Why is that happening and how can I solve this problem?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'event-detail',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="event"> <-- this will never evaluate to 'true'
            ...
        </div>
    `,
})
export class EventCenterDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    event: Event;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private eventBus: EventBus
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.eventBus.event$.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            this.event = event; <-- this assignment seems to have no effect on the component variable
        });
        console.log(this.event); <-- this is 'undefined'
    }
```

Comment: You are saying that if you place a `console.log('something');` right by `this.event = event`, it will print `'something'` to the console as expected? Also, `console.log(this.event); <-- this is 'undefined'` seems natural to be `undefined` at that point because the subscriber function has just been set up, therefore most probably not yet executed (this won't affect the fact that that `ngIf` should become true eventually when the function executes).

Comment: to add to what @acdcjunior just mentioned - try to add <pre>{{ event }}</pre> to your template and see if the actual value changes from false to true.

Answer (score 0):

Only explanation here is that `event` in the subscribe is not coming down properly. You will see that `event` is undefined if you try to print it in the subscribe block

```
...subscribe((event: Event) => {
   console.log(event); // this will print undefined most likely
});
```

Then you have to fix your `EventBus` service